# How to change sbt java options for ivy.home in build.sbt?

Tags: sbt, ivy

I want to change the `sbt.ivy.home` java option in my *build.sbt* file. I tried:

```
javaOptions := Seq("-Dsbt.ivy.home=c:/ivy2/")
```

But it doesn't work.

It work well on the command line:

```
sbt update -Dsbt.ivy.home=c:/ivy/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Ivy home, you can set it via [`ivyPaths`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.7/sxr/sbt/Keys.scala.html#sbt.Keys.ivyPaths) setting.